# Dns pointing domain to ip address

Tags: domain-name-system

Suppose that there are two person first one is original domain owner second one is the fake person who claims to have original domain name. Both have digital ocean account. First person will use the same name servers on his domain as the second person. First person will point the domain to his own ip address and the Second person will point the domain to his own ip address. How would digital ocean knows that who is the owner of the domain name and how would digital ocean point the domain name to the original's person ip address?

Answer (score 1):

In order to designate and configure DNS for the domain you have to have access to the account where the domain was registered, so unless they have your account information at the Registrar they can't set up DNS for the domain.